# How to handle Refresh of a page (ctrl+R, F5) in ionic3

Tags: angular, ionic3

Let's say I have page1 and page2 in an angular application. From page1 I go to page2 by passing some parameters, ie.

```
given: navCtrl: NavController
this.nav.push(Page2, {id: 23});
```

and then in the constructor of page2:

```
given: navParams: NavParams
this.id = this.navParams.get('id');
```

If I refresh the page with ctrl+R or F5 then this.navParams.get('id') doens't have anything...it's null.

Is there anyway to cache parameters?

Thanks

Comment: have you tried fetching your parameters in ngOnInit()

Comment: yes...it's empty

Comment: Can you put up some more code please?  Its hard to tell where the issue is.  Codebliz would be good.

Comment: you can also try using activatedRoute: https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute  This will allow you to access a snapshot of the url and parameters easily and conveniently.

Answer (score 0):

You can cache your data using either the ionic native storage plugin https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/native-storage or sqlite https://ionicframework.com/docs/building/storage